# Why the removal of the Linux Kernel PAE config could reduce the PCIE BAR IO access speed significantly

Tags: linux-kernel, pci-e, debian-stretch

I have a intel atom j1900 board with 2G memory and a FPGA pcie device developed. the
FPGA pcie device information is shown belows:

```sh
root@GNS:~# lspci -s 03:00.0 -vvv
03:00.0 Non-VGA unclassified device: Analog Devices Device 1536
        Subsystem: Analog Devices Device 0007
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 95
        Region 0: Memory at d0b00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Region 1: Memory at d0a00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Region 2: Memory at d0900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Region 3: Memory at d0800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Region 4: Memory at d0700000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Region 5: Memory at d0600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 00000000fee0100c  Data: 4172
        Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [80] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
                        ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 10.000W
                DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
                        RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM not supported, Exit Latency L0s <4us, L1 <1us
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
                LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
                         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
                LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
                         EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
                Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
                Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
                Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
                Status: InProgress-
                VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
                        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
                        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
                        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        Capabilities: [200 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1172 Rev=0 Len=044 <?>
        Kernel driver in use: MyDriver_PCIe_i686
```

when I compiled a kernel without PAE support, the bar io access performance of this device was reduced significantly. here is the test result under none-PAE and PAE kernel. My test
OS environment is debian 9 stretch

| Kernel Version | Bytes Length | Write Throughput | Read Throughput | Write Time | Read Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4.9.0-13-686 | 2048 | 96.45 Mib/s | 16.26 Mib/s | 162 us | 961 us |
| 4.9.0-13-686 | 1024 | 65.10 Mib/s | 15.20 Mib/s | 120 us | 514 us |
| 4.9.0-13-686 | 512 | 38.30 Mib/s | 13.38 Mib/s | 102 us | 292 us |
| 4.9.0-13-686 | 256 | 21.23 Mib/s | 10.56 Mib/s | 92 us | 185 us |
| 4.9.0-13-686 | 128 | 10.97 Mib/s | 7.57 Mib/s | 89 us | 129 us |
| 4.9.0-13-686 | 64 | 5.55 Mib/s | 4.70 Mib/s | 88 us | 104 us |
| 4.9.0-13-686 | 32 | 2.74 Mib/s | 2.81 Mib/s | 89 us | 87 us |
| 4.9.0-13-686 | 8 | 0.69 Mib/s | 0.78 Mib/s | 88 us | 78 us |
| 4.9.0-13-686 | 4 | 0.35 Mib/s | 0.40 Mib/s | 87 us | 77 us |
| 4.9.0-13-686-pae | 2048 | 181.69 Mib/s | 17.48 Mib/s | 86 us | 894 us |
| 4.9.0-13-686-pae | 1024 | 166.22 Mib/s | 17.32 Mib/s | 47 us | 451 us |
| 4.9.0-13-686-pae | 512 | 139.51 Mib/s | 17.13 Mib/s | 28 us | 228 us |
| 4.9.0-13-686-pae | 256 | 108.51 Mib/s | 16.41 Mib/s | 18 us | 119 us |
| 4.9.0-13-686-pae | 128 | 61.04 Mib/s | 15.50 Mib/s | 16 us | 63 us |
| 4.9.0-13-686-pae | 64 | 37.56 Mib/s | 13.95 Mib/s | 13 us | 35 us |
| 4.9.0-13-686-pae | 32 | 18.78 Mib/s | 11.10 Mib/s | 13 us | 22 us |
| 4.9.0-13-686-pae | 8 | 4.36 Mib/s | 5.09 Mib/s | 14 us | 12 us |
| 4.9.0-13-686-pae | 4 | 2.35 Mib/s | 3.39 Mib/s | 13 us | 9 us |
| 4.9.0-18-rt-686-pae | 2048 | 171.70 Mib/s | 17.42 Mib/s | 91 us | 897 us |
| 4.9.0-18-rt-686-pae | 1024 | 159.44 Mib/s | 17.17 Mib/s | 49 us | 455 us |
| 4.9.0-18-rt-686-pae | 512 | 126.01 Mib/s | 16.84 Mib/s | 31 us | 232 us |
| 4.9.0-18-rt-686-pae | 256 | 93.01 Mib/s | 15.88 Mib/s | 21 us | 123 us |
| 4.9.0-18-rt-686-pae | 128 | 54.25 Mib/s | 15.02 Mib/s | 18 us | 65 us |
| 4.9.0-18-rt-686-pae | 64 | 30.52 Mib/s | 13.20 Mib/s | 16 us | 37 us |
| 4.9.0-18-rt-686-pae | 32 | 15.26 Mib/s | 9.77 Mib/s | 16 us | 25 us |
| 4.9.0-18-rt-686-pae | 8 | 4.70 Mib/s | 4.07 Mib/s | 13 us | 15 us |
| 4.9.0-18-rt-686-pae | 4 | 2.35 Mib/s | 2.35 Mib/s | 13 us | 13 us |

Comment: This isn't a programming question.  It seems to be a question about how hardware works.

Comment: it is about how the kernel source code's PAE function  affect the read/write throughput .

Comment: I agree with @stark, this is architectural one, it has nothing to do with the source of Linux kernel. At least directly. Indirectly it's possible that some of the algorithms in the kernel are not well optimized for non-PAE mode, or otherwise, be optimized for PAE, but I do not believe this is the case here.